# Chrome: How to clear programatically all cookies for one site, including 3rd-party tracking cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, javascript, cookies

Is there a programmatic way to clear all the cookies for a single site in chrome, including 3rd-party cookies that were put there by that site?

I know I can do this manually by clicking the padlock next to the URL, then going to Cookies and clicking remove for each one. Is there a way to do this automatically either through javascript or an extension?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021764/where-does-chrome-store-cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can delete cookies by using following javaScript code.

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Or else you can also use following extension for clearing cookies from the browser.

**Delete All Cookies From JavaScript**